# ClobberError while installing virtual environment for conda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I used the command the below command to create a virtual environment for conda with all required bindings in the .yml file.

`conda env create -f virtual_platform_linux.yml`
But I am getting this error:

```
ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.   packages: conda-forge::libgcc-4.8.5-2, conda-forge::libgcc-ng-7.2.0-hdf63c60_3   path: 'lib/libgcc_s.so'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.   packages: conda-forge::libgcc-4.8.5-2, conda-forge::libgcc-ng-7.2.0-hdf63c60_3   path: 'lib/libgcc_s.so.1'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.   packages: conda-forge::libgcc-4.8.5-2, conda-forge::libgcc-ng-7.2.0-hdf63c60_3   path: 'lib/libgomp.so'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.   packages: conda-forge::libgcc-4.8.5-2, conda-forge::libgcc-ng-7.2.0-hdf63c60_3   path: 'lib/libgomp.so.1'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.   packages: conda-forge::libgcc-4.8.5-2, conda-forge::libgcc-ng-7.2.0-hdf63c60_3   path: 'lib/libgomp.so.1.0.0'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.   packages: conda-forge::libgcc-4.8.5-2, conda-forge::libgcc-ng-7.2.0-hdf63c60_3   path: 'lib/libquadmath.so'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.   packages: conda-forge::libgcc-4.8.5-2, conda-forge::libgcc-ng-7.2.0-hdf63c60_3   path: 'lib/libquadmath.so.0'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.   packages: conda-forge::libgcc-4.8.5-2, conda-forge::libgcc-ng-7.2.0-hdf63c60_3   path: 'lib/libquadmath.so.0.0.0'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.   packages: conda-forge::libgcc-4.8.5-2, conda-forge::libstdcxx-ng-7.2.0-hdf63c60_3   path: 'lib/libstdc++.so'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.   packages: conda-forge::libgcc-4.8.5-2, conda-forge::libstdcxx-ng-7.2.0-hdf63c60_3   path: 'lib/libstdc++.so.6'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.   packages: conda-forge::python-3.5.4-0, conda-forge::pytables-3.3.0-np111py35_0   path: 'lib/python3.5/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-35.pyc'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.   packages: conda-forge::python-3.5.4-0, conda-forge::mpmath-0.19-py35_1, conda-forge::pytables-3.3.0-np111py35_0   path: 'lib/python3.5/__pycache__/_bootlocale.cpython-35.pyc'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.   packages: conda-forge::python-3.5.4-0, conda-forge::mpmath-0.19-py35_1, conda-forge::pytables-3.3.0-np111py35_0   path: 'lib/python3.5/__pycache__/_collections_abc.cpython-35.pyc'
```

Comment: Is the environment name (and/or prefix) in the YAML already in use? If so, I'd try explicitly specifying a new name, i.e., `conda env create -f virtual_platform_linux.yml -n my_env`

Comment: @merv renaming the env doesn't work... I am still getting these errors..

Comment: @Yatin thanks for reporting that. Could you post a new question and try to get a minimal example (with YAML and your `conda info` output)? This question is out-of-date. If we get yours answered, then this can be closed as a duplicate. Please @ me the new Q.

Comment: @merv I got the solution yesterday... So I can't reproduce the problem... I will write an answer below.

Answer (score 12):

Try doing `conda clean --all` before running this command. I got this from [this Github discussion](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7038#issuecomment-415893714).

Comment: Note that `conda clean --all` is a blunt tool. It may have worked in your situation, but I generally do not recommend this. For some (e.g., those with installs with envs that exist on multiple drives, or those using softlinks) it will likely break things.

Comment: I don't understand, what are we supposed to do after running conda clean -all?

Comment: @Odisseo try running `conda env create -f virtual_platform_linux.yml` again and see if it works...

Comment: Sadly, conda clean --all does not make the ClobberErrors go away. In my case, the transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path, where the path contains many elements that were clearly added programmatically by some previous automated step and not by me.

Answer (score 1):

Removing 'defaults' from the channels list in my .condarc file resolved this issue for me.

My .condarc file contained the following originally and I simply removed '-defaults' so that I only had conda-forge in my cnannels  :

```
ssl_verify: true 
channels:
   - conda-forge
   - defaults
```